# Rendering Failed. Unable to send Grafana alert image on AWS S3 for rendering to use in Slack alerts

Tags: amazon-s3, grafana, slack

Running 2 docker containers - Grafana and Grafana Image Renderer

My Grafana configuration in Dockers:

```
 GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL: http://render:8081/render
 GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL: http://grafana:3000/
 GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: http://grafana:3000/
 GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: "grafana-image renderer
 GF_INSTALL_IMAGE_RENDERER_PLUGIN: "true"
 GF_LOG_FILTERS: rendering:debug
 GF_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_PROVIDER: "s3"
 GF_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET_URL: https://*bucketname*.s3.*region*.amazonaws.com
 GF_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_S3_REGION: "*region*"
 GF_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY: *access key*
 GF_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_S3_SECRET_KEY: *secret key*
```

**Policy in S3 Bucket:**

```
{
  "Id": "*Policy*",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "*Sid*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Rendering failed is the message I get on my Grafana dashboard**

Answer (score 0):

Your container logs will probably give you the reason.

I suspect the containers can't talk to each-other - i.e. do the hostnames `render` and `grafana` resolve?  Can you e.g. `curl` to http://render:8081 from within the grafana container (using `docker exec -it <container id> /bin/sh`)?

Also, you don't need these env vars:

- `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: "grafana-image renderer` (typo?), since the plug-in functionality is provided by the renderer container
- `GF_INSTALL_IMAGE_RENDERER_PLUGIN: "true"`, since you're using the external renderer and shouldn't need to build a custom container using the separate Dockerfile they supply.